# Is there a way to populate checkboxes based on a radio button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three radio buttons and 17 checkboxes. I would like the radio button that is selected to populate a set of the checkboxes while still giving the user a way to select more if necessary. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript has the power to do this (made far easier by jQuery). You'll want to set an "onClick" function on the radio buttons that can then set the checked value of the checkboxes. For example, this function will turn on/off checkboxs based on what radio button was clicked.

```
function CheckBoxes(selection) {
    if(selection == 1) {
        // Checks checkbox with id "CheckBoxID"
        $("#CheckBoxID").prop("checked", true);
        // Unchecks checkbox with id "CheckBoxID2"
        $("#CheckBoxID2").prop("checked", false);
    }
    else if(selection == 2) {
        // Unchecks checkbox with id "CheckBoxID"
        $("#CheckBoxID").prop("checked", false);
        // Checks checkbox with id "CheckBoxID2"
        $("#CheckBoxID2").prop("checked", true);
    }
    // etc, depending on how many radio buttons and checkboxes you have
}
```

This function can be called with a radio button by doing:

```
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="someName" value="someValue1" onclick="CheckBoxes(1)">
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="someName" value="someValue2" onclick="CheckBoxes(2)">
<input type="radio" id="radio3" name="someName" value="someValue3" onclick="CheckBoxes(3)">
```

This is just how I'd do it off the top of my  head, others will tell you not to assign an OnClick in the html but rather subscribe to it with JavaScript by doing this instead:

```
$('#radio1').click(function(){CheckBoxes(1)});
```

[JSFiddle that shows it off properly](http://jsfiddle.net/BBzSf/18/).

Comment: Not a fan of the "javascript can do this but it would be easier with jquery" phrasing.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer, I agree it does sound a little off.

Answer (score 0):

[Check this FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/BBzSf/1/)

```
$('#a,#b,#c').on('click', function() {

    if( $(this).is(':checked')){
       $('.'+ this.id).show();
    }
});​
```